# Why nested REPLY not working in WP Comments?

Tags: plugins, functions, themes, comments

```
<section class="postcomments">
  <div class="comlist">
    <h3><span>—</span>Comments<span class="comcount"><?php echo get_comments_number(); ?></span></h3>  
    <?php
    $args = array(
      'status' => 'approve',
      'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
      'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    $comments = $comments_query->query($args);
    
    foreach($comments as $comment) :
    ?>    
    <article class="combox badius">
      <div class="col-1">
        <?php echo get_avatar($comment, 64); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <p class="row-1"><span><?php echo get_comment_author(); ?></span><span><?php echo get_comment_date('F j, Y g:i a'); ?></span></p>
        <p class="row-2"><?php echo get_comment_text(); ?></p>
        <!-- <button type="button" name="button">Reply</button> -->
          <?php comment_reply_link( array(
            'depth' => 3,
            'max_depth' => 3,
            'before' => '<button type="button" name="button" class="reply">',
            'after' => '</button>'
          )); ?>
      </div>
    </article>
    
    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    
    <a class="load comments cransition" href=""> Load more Comments </a>
  </div>

    
  <?php
  
    $fields = array(
      'heading_tag' => '<h6>Leave an opinion</h6>',
      'comment_field' => '<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Your opinion matters, but do not spam us!" required></textarea>',
      'author' => '<input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Enter Full Name" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" required>',
      'email'  => '<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email ID" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" required>'
      
    );

    $comment_args = array(
      'title_reply'        => '',
      'fields'             => $fields,
      'comment_field'      => $fields['comment_field'],
      'class_submit'       => 'submit cransition',
      'label_submit'       => 'Post Comment',
      'class_form'         => 'comform',
      'submit_field'       => '%1$s %2$s'
    );


    comment_form($comment_args);

    ?>
  </section>
```

Where am I faltering?

Comment: I don't know comment templates well, but at first glance 1) you're not using comment_class() to generate the CSS classes to show depth; 2) you're passing a hard-coded 3 into the depth arg rather than the actual comment depth.

Comment: I'd look at how one of the default templates handle this for inspiration. They all appear to use wp_list_comments() rather than writing their own loop, and use callbacks within that where they need to customise the HTML. The default HTML might work for you?

Comment: If that's not it, please give us more detail how it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am generating my own loop so that I can use my custom HTML. I am new to creating custom comments templates so I am open to all the suggestions. Hard Coded is the value I am setting to check something as soon as the value of depth is increased beyond 1 the reply button below comments disappears. Default HTML won't work as it doesn't fit the theme requirement and aesthetics. Please guide me where can I use comment_classes?